# Certain proximity detctor

Tags: proximity-sensor, detection

I have a project... Including cats. We have 3 cats, two teenagers and one old man, named Oliver. We want Oliver to be able to eat whenever he wants, but we don't want the other cats to eat whenever they want. I was thinking of designing a box, with some sort of proximity reader in it. Oliver would have a proximity tag, or sometng of the sort, to let him in. He would then have a source of food to eat.

At first, I was thinking RFID tags, but those are expensive and normally only used in businesses.

Then, I thought maybe reed switches would work, but those require semi- powerful magnets to work well.

What should I use to detect the proximity of Oliver, but not either of the other two cats? Thank you.

Comment: You also need to detect when Oliver is there in the company of either or both of the other two; otherwise, they'll learn that they can get food by going there with him.

Comment: This type of design problem is usually solved with RFID.  By their very nature, RFID tags can be very inexpensive.  They are designed as disposable tags for everyday items in stores.  There also are glass RFID tags, which are implanted into pets to ID them if they stray and are later found. Example projects: [RFID cat feeder](http://www.instructables.com/id/RFID-pet-feeder), [RFID cat door](http://www.instructables.com/id/RFID-cat-door).

Comment: Done. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11839

Comment: It wasn't until I started reading the answers that I worked out you meant 'we have three cats: two teenagers, and one old man' rather than 'we have three cats, two teenagers, and one old man'.

Comment: This is awesome, because people actually are giving many other options of detection. Mostly I think that it is due to the involvement of CATS! If this were about dogs, no answers would exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use rfid, have a look at infrared (ir) beacons.
The idea is to have ir led(s) on the cat switched by a small micro controller. Each cat can have a unique blinking pattern which is detected by the base station. The idea is basically the same like a tv remote(constantly transmitting).

A drawback would be having batteries on the cat.

If oliver looks very different from the other cats (color but maybe also size) a webcam and image processing might be an idea to try out too. Frameworks like OpenCV provide a lot of the building blocks for this task.